# How to correctly scale MDIconButton?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to scale an `MDIconButton` based on my brush size. `PushMatrix`/`PullMatrix` appears to be applying to all following widgets in the canvas, instead of just the button widget as expected.

I have found that this does not occur with a stock standard kivy `Button` widget, but was hoping to continue using the kivymd `MDIconButton` for the animations and other behaviors / dressings.

Currently I use a label over the top to add additional details to my button, which makes this implementation seem the most straightforward in my mind.
I imagine the problem is being caused by one of the behaviors the `MDIconButton` inherits from, but have not yet been able to isolate exactly which one.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivymd.button import MDRaisedButton, MDIconButton

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string('''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: dp(42)
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        ##Button:
        MDIconButton:
            _scale: 1
            on_release: self._scale = (((self._scale*3) + 1) % 3) / 3
            ##text: 'brush'
            icon: 'brush'
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            text_color: 1,1,1,1
            canvas.before:
                PushMatrix
                Scale:
                    origin: self.center
                    x: self._scale or 1.
                    y: self._scale or 1.
            canvas.after:
                PopMatrix

    Widget:
        id: palette
        size_hint_y: None
        height: dp(42)
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: 1,0,0
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

    Widget:
        id: sketchpad
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgb: 1,1,0
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
''')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

The MDIconButton `icon: 'brush'` should cycle between 3 sizes, leaving the rest of the widgets at their normal size (correct behavior seen when replacing `MDIconButton` with `Button` and changing `icon:` to `text:`).

Is there a better/different way to change the icon size, avoiding this problem altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question asks how to **correctly** scale the `MDIconButton`. I cannot claim that this is `correct`, but here is a hack that accomplishes it. Note that the `icon` is just a character in a font, so its size can be adjusted by adjusting the font size. To accomplish this, I extended `BoxLayout` (only because it is your `root`) to include a `set_font_size()` method:

```
class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    def set_font_size(self, *args):
        butt = self.ids.mdIconButt
        label = butt.ids.content

        # adjust font size for the icon
        label.font_size *= 1.1

        # adjust the size of the buttons containers
        butt.height *= 1.1
        butt.width *= 1.1
        butt.parent.height *= 1.1
```

Then, in your `kv` string:

```
MyBoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: dp(42)
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        ##Button:
        MDIconButton:
            id: mdIconButt  # id to make it easy to find this widget
            on_release: root.set_font_size()  # call the new method
            icon: 'brush'
            theme_text_color: 'Custom'
            text_color: 1,1,1,1
    .
    .
    .
```

Note that this is fiddling with the `MDIconButton` internals, so expect it to break on any change to `kivyMD`.

You can actually accomplish most of this by simply replacing your `on_release` for the `MDIconButton` to:

```
on_release: self.ids.content.font_size *= 1.1
```

But then only the icon size changes, and the `MDIconButton` and its container do not.